# Advanced checkbox inputs - let user choose a single div

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox

**Edit:** Thank You for all replies! I forgot to mention it would be better if it was more like `<input type="radio">` and only one theme could be chosen. Here is what I already have (not much though). The function when **only one input could be checked does not work**. Also, there's missing function which should **uncheck the radio button when it's already checked.

The link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=8JzTuwDU7d). Hope it works now.
**

---

I'm creating a 3-step form, which should have a theme chooser. Those themes are display as divs.

Single div looks such as this:

```
<div class="theme">Theme</div>
```

**How do I get the the value of the clicked div?**

**URL params?**

```
<div class="theme"><a href="?theme=2">Theme</a></div>
```

**Or is it possible via some Form input?**

```
<div class="theme"><input type="checkbox">???</div>
```

Comment: the link does not wrok.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.theme').on('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).html(); // Here you go
    alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the text inside the div which is **Theme** in this case:

```
<div class="theme">Theme</div>
```

then:

```
$('.theme').click(function () {
     console.log($(this).text()); // will get you Theme
});
```

If you want to get all the content inside the div present :

```
<div class="theme">
<a href="?theme=2">Theme</a>
</div>
```

then:

```
$('.theme').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).html()); // will give you  <a href="?theme=2">Theme</a>
    });
```

If you want the text between the link tag then:

```
$('.theme').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).find("a").text()); // will give you theme
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use the html data attribute.

HTML

```
<div class="theme" data-theme="2">Theme</div>
```

Then you can retrieve this using jquery:

```
$('.theme').on('click', function () {
  var value = $(this).data("theme");
alert(value);
});
```

Here is a fiddle that shows an example http://jsfiddle.net/f5VH6/